# To "get something going"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, german-to-english

I am looking for the best ways to express "to get something going" in German. It seems like here are some intuitive expressions, but there seem to be limitations to them that I don't quite understand. Let me provide some examples. In English, these are all common phrases:

1. > I need to get myself going (I've been lazy all day, there are things to do)!
2. > Let's get this party going!
3. > Let's keep the conversations/discussions going between us.

Now, it seems that "in Gang setzen/bringen/halten" sort of (?) works for examples 1 and 3 (correct me if I'm wrong), so that I could write

1. > Ich muss mich in Gang bringen.
2. …
3. > Wir müssen die Unterhaltungen im Gang halten.

Which leads me to believe that it should work for 2 as well, but it seems not to. This is turn leads me to believe that "in Gang bringen" is not best translated as to get something going, but means something a bit different. I have heard "zum Laufen bringen" which seems to work better for 2, but not as much for 1 and 3.

Comment: For 1 *aufraffen* is the verb to use, while for 3 it is something like *Lass' uns in Kontakt bleiben*.

Comment: FWIW: *to keep something going* is not the same as *to get something going*.

Comment: Consider the word *loslegen*.

Comment: After further research, I see, "in Gaenge kommen". This seems to fit well with 1. But 2?

Comment: *in **die** Gänge kommen* could be right, but is rather colloquial. Just like *in die Pötte kommen* or similar is heard around here, but probably local. *In Gang kommen* is the more usual form but not exactly fitting in the first or second sentence (in 2, *in Gang bringen* could work). But as I said, consider *loslegen* or *sich aufraffen*.

Comment: Etwas ins rollen bringen!

Answer (score 1):

1. I need to get myself going (I've been lazy all day, there are things to do)!

> - Ich muss mich endlich aufraffen / aufrappeln!
> - Ich muss meinen inneren Schweinehund überwinden!

2. Let's get this party going!

> Lasst uns die Party starten! / Starten wir die Party, Leute!

3. Let's keep the conversations/discussions going between us.

> Wir sollten im Gespräch bleiben.

Answer (score 1):

1. I need to get myself going (I've been lazy all day, there are things to do)!

can also be translated by a rather slangy

> Ich muss jetzt mal langsam aus dem Quark kommen kommen.

Quite common, but sloppy:

> Zeit für mich, endlich den Arsch hochzukriegen.

I think, 'in die Gänge kommen' is the best version.

2. Let's get this party going!

> Dann bringen wir mal die Party ein bisschen in Schwung!
>
> Dann wollen wir mal (jetzt) ein bisschen Schwung / Dampf / Pep / Drive / Schub in die Party bringen!
>
> Dann wollen wir diese (müde) Party mal auf Touren bringen.
>
> Dann lass uns die Party mal ein bisschen anschieben.

3. Let's keep the conversations / discussions going between us.

> Lass uns in Kontakt bleiben.
>
> Es wäre schön, wenn wir unseren Dialog aufrechterhalten / noch weiterführen könnten.
>
> Wir sollten unser Gespräch / unseren Kontakt nicht einschlafen lassen.